# TFLearn import issue - no module core_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am testing out the TFLearn library for using TensorFlow but can't import it due to some config issue. I installed it as required in TFLearn tutorial though. Thankful for any help.

```
>>> import tflearn as tf
>    import tflearn

  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config

ImportError: cannot import name config
```

Answer (score 3):

This is caused due to incompatibilitiy of TFlearn and Tensorflow. They may be of different version. Hence, to resolve the issue, uninstall tensorflow and tflearn and reinstall them using the following code -

```
pip uninstall tflearn 
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install -I tensorflow==0.12.1
pip install -I tflearn==0.2.1
```

Comment: Done but I do not have enough reputation yet for it to appear publicly, sorry about that.